# Why my Ionic/Firebase subscribe is called 3 times?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code, I can't see why my code is executed 3 times.

```
advertenciaMantto() {
  this.afs.doc('Core/Programador').valueChanges().subscribe(async (data) => {
    await this.afs.firestore.doc(`Core/Programador`).get().then(async data => {
      if (data.data().manager.prevencion) {
        this.presentAlert();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Can you help me, please?

**EDIT**

I tried with .pipe(first()) and it works, the problem is that when I make a change in my firestore data, it does not execute because it has already been executed once.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.subscribe()` method which has a different behavior from `.get()`
the first time a subscriber runs, it always returns no documents, then it run again and return documents from you local cache, and then it runs one more time returning the documents from remote (firebase), and then it starts listening for changes in the documents

Comment: omg, well I need to redo my function following the logic that you have established so that it does not make more calls than necessary, although I think I already solved it, what I don't know is if it is the right way to solve it. My solution is below, but thank you very much for showing me how the logic of my function works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
async advertenciaMantto() {
  await this.afs.firestore.doc(`Core/Programador`).get().then(async doc => {
    if (doc.data().manager.prevencion) {
      this.presentAlert();
    } else {
      this.alertaSubs = this.afs.doc('Core/Programador').valueChanges().subscribe(async () => {
        await this.afs.firestore.doc(`Core/Programador`).get().then(async doc => {
          if (doc.data().manager.prevencion) {
            this.alertaSubs.unsubscribe();
            this.presentAlert();
          }
        })
      });
    }
  });
}
```